# Get source from dimens.xml

Tags: android, dimensions

I have java file

```
private void drawLevelNumber(Canvas canvas)
{
  int y = 0;
  int x;
  int level = mLevelManager.getLevelIndex() + 1;
  if (level < 10) {
    x = 145;
    mFont.paintChar(Character.forDigit(level, 10), x, y, canvas,
                    mDisplayScale, mDisplayDX, mDisplayDY);
  } else if (level < 100) {
```

in my gameview , how to change value 145 from x=145 to value from dimens.xml

Comment: `x=(int)getResources.getDimension(R.dimen.your_dimen_name);`

Comment: getResources cannot be resolved.

Comment: May be your code is not in Activity, if I am right, then try JPasukmit's answer in Fragment, but if you want this to happen in adapter or other classes, then you must pass Activity context and replace it with getContext()

Answer (score 1):

try using

```
getContext().getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.xxx));
```

or

```
getContext().getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.xxx));
```

depends on your usage

Comment: If it helps to solve your problem, then please accept the answer. So that anyone who will encounter same issue can find the solution. :)